# UnixTime on spark / java

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have the following dataframe :

```
+------------------------+
| Tracking_Time          |
+------------------------+
|2020-02-18 14:50:07     |
|2020-02-17 17:15:45     |
+------------------------+
```

I use the following code :

```
df.withColumn("current_date", expr("reflect('java.lang.System', 'currentTimeMillis')"))
  .withColumn("Tracking_Time_ms", unix_timestamp(col("Tracking_Time")));
```

I get the following output

```
+------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+
| Tracking_Time          |current_date            |Tracking_Time_ms        |
+------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+
|2020-02-18 14:50:07     |1598108268389           |1582037407              |              
|2020-02-17 17:15:45     |1598108270182           |1581959745              |
+------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+
```

How can I convert the format of `Tracking_Time_ms` to the format of `current_date`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unix time stamp is a running total of seconds. This count starts at the Unix Epoch on January 1st, 1970 at UTC.

So the values you see under Tracking_Time_ms are actually in seconds.

To convert it to ms (to be the same as current_date) you need to multiply it by 1000.